# How do you unable auto multi-line on vscode with prettier?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I like all the features in Prettier but having auto multi-lines is annoying. Is it possible to have it turned off?

like when adding multiple CSS selectors and HTML attributes, I want to keep them in one line instead of having each selector/attribute on its own line.

for example, on CSS I want it to look like this

```
h1, h2 {
  color: #1B3E66;
}
```

instead of automatically doing this on save

```
h1,
h2 {
  color: #1B3E66;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Prettier has only a very limited set of configurations and this is not one of them. For the full config options for prettier see: https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html