# Prettier config on CSS + VS Code (ID block)

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, formatting, prettier

Recently started to work with Prettier in VSC and so far so good; the only issue I found is the "diagram" of the ID. How can I adjust the format?. My **Prettier: Print Width**'s value is 120, so is not that.

*Exp. (Prettier on)*

```
#mail_user,
#pass_user,
#name_user,
#cardValid {
  font-size: 55px;
  padding: 20px 14px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 90px;
}
```

*I'm looking something like:*

```
#mail_user, #pass_user, #name_user, #cardValid {
  font-size: 55px;
  padding: 20px 14px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 90px;
}
```

Few lines and just simply like it more. Thx in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60981883/how-do-you-unable-auto-multi-line-on-vscode-with-prettier - Looks like this isn't an option. Prettier is fairly opinionated.

Comment: Took me 1h of friutless search in this site to decide posting a new Q'. Sorry about that and thx for the reply.